# Find postgresql query PID from Rails (Track a query's ID)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

In Rails, I'm starting a regular query such as:

```
MyTable.where("user_id = ?",5)
```

[The acutual query I'm running takes a long time so I will have time to perform the next steps.]

Then, in Postgres, I run the command:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

This returns a list of current queries to the database with PID's and other information. Included in that list is my query (and I know because it shows the query parameters being run). My question is how do I track a certain query? After starting the query in rails, I want to know the PID of the query and other information the 'pg_stat_activity' table can provide, but I have no way of finding my exact query other than matching the query text or a hacky way of trying to compare timestamps.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You could first get the pid from your client app with `select pg_backend_pid()` (pid doesn't refer to the query but to the entire client session)

Answer (score 1):

If that is the only query you are running at that point from rails app, you can look at the application_name column to differentiate it from the rest.

If not, i can't think of any other way than to compare the actual query